# Use ngSwitch to switch between components in Angular 2?

Tags: angularjs, angular, ng-switch, angular2-components

I've just started experimenting with Angular 2 and ran into this question:

Let's say I create a web app with a Menu Bar on top. Each menu item should load a different component.

What is the "right" way of doing this? So far my idea is to use ngSwitch for that.

Template:

```
 <div [ngSwitch]="value">
      <p *ngSwitchWhen="0"><component1></component1></p>
      <p *ngSwitchWhen="1"><component2></component2></p>
 </div>
```

And just change "value" according to the item. Is that a good solution, or did i miss a better one?

Comment: You have the router for that. Using links and routing, you can easily copy-paste the url and get back to where you were.

Comment: makes too much sense! thanks, @jornare

Comment: No worries :) I made it an answer since it satisfies your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the router for that. Using links and routing, you can easily copy-paste the url and get back to where you were.

Comment: what if you are not interested in URLs. What if you just want to switch out one object for another?